Dataframe Replace NaN whith random in range
I have a Dataframe in Python whith NaN, as this:
import pandas as pd
details = {
    'info1' : [10,None,None,None,None,None,15,None,None,None,5],
    'info2' : [15,None,None,None,10,None,None,None,None,None,20],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(details)
print(df)





info1
info2




0
10
15


1
nan
nan


2
nan
nan


3
nan
nan


4
nan
10


5
nan
nan


6
15
nan


7
nan
nan


8
nan
nan


9
nan
nan


10
5
20



How to replace NaNs with the random number (e.g., uniform) in a specific range (based on rows that have values), as this:


Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like code formatting (print(df)) or table formatting (print(df.to_markdown()).

You can achieve this in a vectorial way (see below)

For a vectorial solution, directly call np.random.uniform with the ffill/bfill as boundaries:
import numpy as np

df[:] = np.random.uniform(df.ffill(), df.bfill())

Output (with np.random.seed(0)):
        info1      info2
0   10.000000  15.000000
1   13.013817  12.275584
2   12.118274  11.770529
3   12.187936  10.541135
4   14.818314  10.000000
5   13.958625  15.288949
6   15.000000  19.255966
7   14.289639  10.871293
8   14.797816  18.326198
9    7.218432  18.700121
10   5.000000  20.000000

Note
As pointed out by @wjandrea, the behavior of uniform is not officially supported when low > high*. If you want a robust solution, use my original approach with an intermediate array and sort:
import numpy as np

# ensure the low boundary is before the high
tmp = np.sort(np.dstack([df.ffill(),
                         df.bfill()]),
              axis=2)

# generate random numbers between low and high
df[:] = np.random.uniform(tmp[..., 0], tmp[..., 1])

(*)

If high < low, the results are officially undefined and may eventually
raise an error, i.e. do not rely on this function to behave when
passed arguments satisfying that inequality condition.


I just noticed this in the docs: "If high < low, the results are officially undefined and may eventually raise an error". So I guess you actually should sort (like you did originally, in revision 1).

@wjandrea that was indeed my first intuition and then I though "what happens if we don't sort?"? I'll add this as comment.

Try:
def get_rand(a, b):
    if a == b:
        return None
    if a > b:
        a, b = b, a
    return np.random.randint(low=a, high=b)


tmp = pd.concat([df.ffill().add_suffix("_1"), df.bfill().add_suffix("_2")], axis=1)

for c in df.columns:
    df.loc[df[c].isna(), c] = tmp.apply(
        lambda row: get_rand(a=row[c + "_1"], b=row[c + "_2"]), axis=1
    )

print(df)

Prints (for example):
    info1  info2
0    10.0   15.0
1    11.0   13.0
2    10.0   10.0
3    14.0   14.0
4    12.0   10.0
5    10.0   12.0
6    15.0   13.0
7     7.0   11.0
8    13.0   19.0
9    13.0   11.0
10    5.0   20.0


you can replace nan values with a random range of numbers like this:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

details = {
    'info1' : [10,None,None,None,None,None,15,None,None,None,5],
    'info2' : [15,None,None,None,10,None,None,None,None,None,20],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(details)

df = df.map(lambda x: x if not np.isnan(x) else np.random.randint(10,15))

print(df)

Results:
   info1  info2
0    10.0   15.0
1    11.0   13.0
2    11.0   14.0
3    10.0   12.0
4    13.0   10.0
5    12.0   14.0
6    15.0   10.0
7    13.0   14.0
8    14.0   11.0
9    13.0   13.0
10    5.0   20.0


Tks, but the range of rand changes accord to the "last" and "previous" values on rows (see figure)
